# Pushing to multiple github account

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm in a situation where I currently required to push to multiple github accounts.
For simplicity let's take two accounts.

```
https://github.com/user1/repositoryName
https://github.com/user2/repositoryName
```

I used to work with user1, which is my personal account. 
User2 is my work account.

Now, when I did git push to my work account:

```
remote: Permission to user2/repositoryName.git denied to user1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nitte93/reactogram.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

After some browing, I came to know that I need to setup a seperate SSH-key for each account.

So I did.

For personal

```
cd .ssh 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user1@example.com"
 //gave it a name of personal
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/personal
ssh-add ~/.ssh/personal

Added it to github>settings>ssh.
```

For work

```
cd .ssh 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user1@work.com"
 //gave it a name of work
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/work
ssh-add ~/.ssh/work

Added it to github>settings>ssh.


ls .ssh
Had both the files.
Namely: peronal personal.pub work work.pub defaultones
```

Next I did:

```
   vi config
```

Update it to

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal

Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal
```

Varified: ssh -T git@github.com
Got a message :

```
Hi user1! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

The thing is my work link is of  the form: https://github.com/work and not 
work.github.com
But only user2(work) has access to it. User2(personal) doesn't.

Next when I try to push to my work repo. I keep getting the same error.

```
remote: Permission to user1/repositoryName.git denied to user2.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nitte93/reactogram.git/': The requested
```

I know there are several other questions dealing with the same issue. But I believe I followed them properly. I'm not sure if I'm  missing any step. 
Please guide me if I'm missing any of the steps.
I want to be able to push to both the repos.

Comment: If you are using SSH as a remote to Github then, your remote URI should be `git@github.com:user1/repo.git`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SSH as a remote to GitHub then you should not be using remote URLs that use `https://`. Your remotes should look something like this:

```
git@github.com:user1/repository.git
```